# Mozilla Firefox Plugin for VLC

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, vlc-media-player

I would like to use the extension chrome radio for Chrome but it says that I need to install the VLC Mozilla Firefox plugin.

Does anyone know how to do that? (I looked for it, but couldn't find it)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/): the VLC plugin for Mozilla Firefox is included.

Comment: I did install it but I don't see the mozilla plugin. I should have mentioned that I am referring to this: chrome-extension://hgjdhckebbdoobhniheihpdogeoeelbn/help.html#download-vlc